# How to mark nest area in double bridge experiment?

Tags: ant

[image]
In my setup, I am lacking a nest. I'd need some way of telling the ants to bring food back to a first container, instead of just accumulating at the food source.

Comment: Presumably you have a queen, or at least some larvae?

Comment: Ah yes that might work, or maybe I could put one end of the setup close to a nest outside

Comment: Could you please explain what this is all about and what your question about biology is.